# Why does the dataset not print?

Tags: clojure

The following code seems to run fine. I see it print "inside main" but I don't see a dataset being printed. small-sample.csv contains several lines like below. What is the correct way to print a dataset?

I modified the code and now see that the program throws an exception. If I remove the print, I don't get an exception but I see no output. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
;;small-sample.csv file
Gomez,Addams,father
Morticia,Addams,mother
Pugsley,Addams,brother
...

(use 'incanter.core
     'incanter.io)

(ns getting-data.core
  (:require [incanter.core :as incanter]) (:require [incanter.io :as io])
)

(defn -main
  "Command-line entry point."
  [& raw-args]
  (try
    (println "inside main")
      (print((io/read-dataset "data/small-sample.csv")))
  (catch Exception e (prn "in catch1"))))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should simply remove the parenthesis in `io/read-dataset`, like this:

```
(print (io/read-dataset "data/small-sample.csv"))
```

from the [docs](http://clojuredocs.org/incanter/incanter.io/read-dataset):

> Returns a dataset read from a file or a URL.

The extra parenthesis tries to evaluate the data-set